# Как удалить несколько дочерних элементов по клику

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка, необходимо при клики на неё удалить все дочерние элементы из родительского элемента `div class="col-sm-12"` включая саму кнопку. Не пойму что не так?

```js
var buttonClose = document.querySelector('button.close');
var parentElem = buttonClose.parentNode;
buttonClose.addEventListener('click', removeChildren);
function removeChildren(parentElem) {
  while (parentElem.lastChild) {
    parentElem.removeChild(parentElem.lastChild);
  }
}
```

```css
.data {
  border:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <button type="button" class="close">
       <span>&times;</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="data">
    <li>Яблоко</li>
    <li>Груша</li>
    <li>Слива</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш пример будет работать, если у функции `removeChildren` убрать аргумент из объявления.

```js
var buttonClose = document.querySelector('button.close');
var parentElem = buttonClose.parentNode;
buttonClose.addEventListener('click', removeChildren);

function removeChildren() { //убрать аргумент из функции
  while (parentElem.lastChild) {
    parentElem.removeChild(parentElem.lastChild);
  }
}
```

```css
.data {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <button type="button" class="close">
       <span>&times;</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="data">
    <li>Яблоко</li>
    <li>Груша</li>
    <li>Слива</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: получается, если в функции есть параметр(он же аргумент), то функция начинает искать вызов removeChildren('какие либо данные'); - она его не находит и поэтому скрипт не работает. Правильно понял?

Comment: @ikar Дело в области видимости переменных. Вы через  `addEventListener` не передаете никаких параметров, поэтому внутри функции `parentElem`=`undefined` Однако если вы не объявляете эту переменную в параметрах функции, находится глобальная с таким именем.

Comment: @Crantisz, как раз один параметр через addEventListener передается, и parentElem внутри не `undefined`

Comment: @Grundy Да точно, передается `event`, который, конечно, не содержит нужных элементов. Вообщем ваш ответ как раз объясняет суть

Comment: Не хочу вызывать холиваров, но я так и не понял, если в двух словах объяснить кто-то может. - Почему в функции параметр parentElem помешал отработке всего кода?

Comment: @ikar, _Ошибка заключается в том, что removeChildren используется в качестве обработчика события. А первым параметром в обработчик передается объект события._

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка заключается в том, что `removeChildren` используется в качестве обработчика события. А первым параметром в обработчик передается объект события.

Таким образом внутри функции `parentElem` не был бы переменной объявленной ранее.

Для решения можно

1. Не использовать параметр, тогда будет использована объявленная ранее переменная
2. привязать к функции параметр с помощью [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind): `removeChildren.bind(buttonClose,parentElem)`
3. использовать `this` внутри функции. В простом вызове он будет ссылаться на саму кнопу, поэтому используя свойство [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) у `this` можно получить нужный контейнер
4. установить `this`, в значение parentElem, с помощью [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), тогда `this` внутри функции и будет нужным элементом.

Пример

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button.close')).forEach((buttonClose, i) => {
  var parentElem = buttonClose.parentNode;

  if (i == 0) {
    buttonClose.addEventListener('click', removeChildren1);
    return;
  }
  if (i == 1) {
    buttonClose.addEventListener('click', removeChildren2.bind(buttonClose, parentElem));
    return;
  }
  if (i == 2) {
    buttonClose.addEventListener('click', removeChildren3);
  }
  if (i == 3) {
    buttonClose.addEventListener('click', removeChildren4.bind(parentElem));
  }

  function removeChildren1() { //убрать аргумент из функции
    while (parentElem.lastChild) {
      parentElem.removeChild(parentElem.lastChild);
    }
  }

});



function removeChildren2(parentElem) { //убрать аргумент из функции
  while (parentElem.lastChild) {
    parentElem.removeChild(parentElem.lastChild);
  }
}

function removeChildren3() { //использовать `this`
  var parentElem = this.parentNode;
  while (parentElem.lastChild) {
    parentElem.removeChild(parentElem.lastChild);
  }
}

function removeChildren4() { //использовать `this`
  while (this.lastChild) {
    this.removeChild(this.lastChild);
  }
}
```

```css
.data {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <button type="button" class="close">
       <span>&times;</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="data">
    <li>Яблоко</li>
    <li>Груша</li>
    <li>Слива</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <button type="button" class="close">
       <span>&times;</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="data">
    <li>Яблоко</li>
    <li>Груша</li>
    <li>Слива</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <button type="button" class="close">
       <span>&times;</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="data">
    <li>Яблоко</li>
    <li>Груша</li>
    <li>Слива</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <button type="button" class="close">
       <span>&times;</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="data">
    <li>Яблоко</li>
    <li>Груша</li>
    <li>Слива</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для такой задачи и мудрить-то особо нечего:

```js
document.querySelector('button.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.parentNode.innerHTML = '';
});
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <button type="button" class="close">
       <span>&times;</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="data">
    <li>Яблоко</li>
    <li>Груша</li>
    <li>Слива</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```